# Insert values from a dataframe into another dataframe based on common key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering two Pandas dataframes:

df1:

```
name    key
a       0
b       1
c       0
d       0
e       1
```

df2:

```
key     value_1     value_2
0       11          12
0       21          22
1       111         112
1       121         122
1       131         132
```

How to obtain a new tidy Pandas dataframe *df3* that inserts in *df1* the values of *df2* selected in function of the values in the column *type* of *df1* and *df2*:

df3:

```
name    key     value_1     value_2 
a       0       11          12
a       0       21          22
b       1       111         112
b       1       121         122
b       1       131         132
c       0       11          12
c       0       21          22
d       0       11          12
d       0       21          22
e       1       111         112
e       1       121         122
e       1       131         132
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
It's also best to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to enable others to help you. 
And check [How to make pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1):

#### Merge pandas dataframes

We can perform joins on your two pandas dataframes `df1` and `df3`.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on=['key'], right_on = ['key'])
```

We can write it more concisely this way

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['key'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

> left_on : label or list, or array-like Field names to join on in left
> DataFrame. Can be a vector or list of vectors of the length of the
> DataFrame to use a particular vector as the join key instead of
> columns
>
> right_on : label or list, or array-like Field names to join on in
> right DataFrame or vector/list of vectors per left_on docs